# OpenMP behaviour detecting CPU and thread

Tags: multithreading

I'm at very beginning with OpenMP, i just compiled with `gcc -fopenmp openmp_c_helloworld.c` the following piece of code:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int th_id, nthreads;
  #pragma omp parallel private(th_id)
  {
    th_id = omp_get_thread_num();
    printf("Hello World from thread %d\n", th_id);
    #pragma omp barrier
    if ( th_id == 0 ) {
      nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
      printf("There are %d threads\n",nthreads);
    }
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I just run the executable on a quad-core Intel CPU with HyperThreading and i obtain the following output:

```
Hello World from thread 2
Hello World from thread 0
Hello World from thread 3
Hello World from thread 1
There are 4 threads
```

Technically speaking i have 8 thread available on my CPU and 4 CPU-core, why OpenMP shows me only 4 thread?

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply, I think it's because OpenMP looks for the number of CPU's (cores) rather than the number of processor threads.
See [this](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/) page: `

> Implementation default - usually the number of CPUs on a node, though
>   it could be dynamic (see next bullet).

Something you could try out is setting the number of threads in your program to be equal to the number of processor threads and see if there's a performance improvement (you'll have to create your own benchmarking program).
In parallel programming, good performance is obtained when the number of worker threads are equal to the number of processor threads. You can keep a thread or two extra for I/O as well.